# Android - Set contents to a Tab (Fragment)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I'm new to android and I can't seem to find practical reference to this very simple problem:

- I have a New Empty project, with 3 tabs.
- I managed to add ActionbarSherlock for compatibility (though it's not relevant at this instance).

I have an array of items (plain text) I want to list on the 1st tab, and I need to know how to update the Tab on runtime.

This is the code I have for the Fragments Section (created by default by Android SDK):

```
public static class sectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public sectionFragment() {}


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

(this is the default class. I didn't touch it, yet. It will simply add a 1, 2 and 3 to each tab, as dummy contents.)

**How can I add content (listView) to the first tab?**

**How do I reach the instance (element) of one of the Tabs?**

Please, don't suggest completely different approaches (I'm having a bad time with this already). Follow my idea and help me reach this simple goal.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, use [Fragment Transaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html)